# QuickFlip JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using quicklfip (http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin) for Chinese character flashcards. The front panel will have the character and the back panel will have the definition. The problem I am having is that I want to show example sentences but only when the back panel is visible. There doesn't seem to be any callback function. Any JQuery experts have any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of headscratching I finally came up with the answer.. and it was simpler than I thought. All I needed to do was create 2 functions like so:

```
function showExamples() {
            $('#examples').show();
        }
        function hideExamples() {
            $('#examples').hide();
        }
```

and then place an `<a>` tag on each side of the card that would not only flip the card, but also call the above functions! Like this:

```
<a class="quickFlipCta" href="#" onclick="javascript:showExamples()">Click to flip</a>
```

and

```
<a class="quickFlipCta" href="#" onclick="javascript:hideExamples()">Click to flip</a>
```

Job done!

Answer (score 0):

Per the page, there is an updated plugin with callbacks.  You could use the onBefore and/or just do it via content:

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

```
$("#flipbox").flip({
    direction:'tb',
    onBefore: function(){
            console.log('before starting the animation');
    },
    onAnimation: function(){
            console.log('in the middle of the animation');
    },
    onEnd: function(){
            console.log('when the animation has already ended');
    }
})
```